# How to change screen resolution of android phone using IONIC?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, screen-resolution, image-enlarge

Can I change my android phone's screen resolution using Ionic?
Purpose is to enlarge font and images.
This will be applicable to all apps and home screen for mobile.
is there any package in ionic to do so?

Comment: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/text-zoom

Comment: Thanks for reply Najam.The Text Zoom API provides the ability to change Web View text size for visual accessibility.
We want to change appearance of all app and home screen. So its not possible using above method.